# How to store a html div into a php session?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, session

I need help in storing my div into a php session.

```
<div name = "divResults">
(display results from mysql)
</div>
```

What i need to do exactly is:

->Search records through dates.
->Results will be shown on next page.
->There will be a button to send an email.
->Results in my div will be send through an email to a user.

I'm able to send an email but I couldn't send the results. I've tried using this

This are my codes for results page after searching through dates :

```
<div name = "divResults">
<?php

$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Records WHERE Date = '".$sdbStart."' AND Records.SerialNumber NOT IN (SELECT SerialNumber FROM ImportData WHERE Date ='".$adbStart."') ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");

                            $_SESSION['getquery'] = $getquery;
echo "<table id=wTable>";
                            echo "<table id=hTable style=width:800px; border=1px;>
                                    <tr style=background-color:black;color:yellow;font-size:18px;>
                                    <th style=width:25px>ID</th>
                                    <th style=width:200px>Username</th>
                                    <th style=width:175px>Date</th>
                                    <th style=width:225px>Serial Number</th>
                                    <th style=width:200px>Location</th>
                                    </tr>";

                            echo "</table>";
                            echo "<div id ='test' style=width:820px;height:200px;overflow:auto;>";
                            echo "<table id=dTable width=800px border=1px>";  

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
                            {
                            $r +=1;
                            echo "<tr style=color:black;background-color:lightgrey;font-size:13px;>";
                            echo "<td style=width:25px>" . $r . "</td>";
                            echo "<td style=width:200px>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td style=width:175px >" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td style=width:225px>" . $row['SerialNumber'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td style=width:200px>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo "</table>";  
                            echo "</table>";
                            echo "</div>";
?>
</div>



<form method = "POST" action = "email-controller.php">

        <font style ="color:orange"><b>From :</b></font>
        <input type = "text" name = "sender" id = "sender" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>" class = "sender">

        <font style ="color:orange"><b>Send to :</b></font>
        <input type = "text" name = "recipient" id = "recipient">

        <input type = "submit" name = "sendEmail" id = "sendEmail" value = "Send">
        </form>
```

This are my email-controller.php codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=autogeneratereport.php" />
</head>

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'un', 'pw');

mysql_select_db('db');

$sender = $_POST['sender'];
$recipient = $_POST['recipient'];
$_SESSION['divData'] = $_POST['divData'];

session_start();
$_SESSION['sender'] = $sender;
$_SESSION['recipient'] = $recipient;

$senderQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = '".$sender."'");
$senderData = mysql_fetch_array($senderQuery);
$_SESSION['senderEmail'] = $senderData['Email'];
$_SESSION['senderFN'] = $senderData['FullName'];


$recipientQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users Where Email = '".$recipient."'");
$recipientData = mysql_fetch_array($recipientQuery);
$_SESSION['recipientEmail'] = $recipientData['Email'];
$_SESSION['recipientFN'] = $recipientData['FullName'];


$getquery = $_SESSION['getquery'];



?>
```

Comment: Please share your code . What you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following code :

```
            $html = "<table id=wTable>
                <table id=hTable style=width:800px; border=1px;>
                                <tr style=background-color:black;color:yellow;font-size:18px;>
                                <th style=width:25px>ID</th>
                                <th style=width:200px>Username</th>
                                <th style=width:175px>Date</th>
                                <th style=width:225px>Serial Number</th>
                                <th style=width:200px>Location</th>
                                </tr>
                </table>
                        <div id ='test' style=width:820px;height:200px;overflow:auto;>
                        <table id=dTable width=800px border=1px>";  

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
                        {
                        $r +=1;
                        $html .= "<tr style=color:black;backgroundcolor:lightgrey;font-size:13px;>
                                  <td style=width:25px>" . $r . "</td>
                                  <td style=width:200px>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>
                                  <td style=width:175px >" . $row['Date'] . "</td>
                                  <td style=width:225px>" . $row['SerialNumber'] . "</td>
                                 <td style=width:200px>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>
                                 </tr>";
                        }
                        $html .= "</table>
                                  </table>
                                 </div>";

            echo $html;
            $_SESSION['divData'] = $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a date in session variable and using this date on next page you can fetch record and send mail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're storing the `div` into `session`.

You just have to do is, get some results from your DB, show them on page, and if someone clicks on send email button, create that `div` and populate with the data, and send it. simple mate.